# Is the mauve paper still actual?

Tags: proof-of-stake, sharding, mauve-paper

I would like to know if the mauve paper is still actual or it is better to rely on the [sharding FAQ](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Sharding-FAQs) and [Proof of stake FAQ](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Proof-of-Stake-FAQs) or on other sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mauve paper has been deprecated for about 2 years. Yes, refer to the FAQs that you mentioned, with https://notes.ethereum.org/SCIg8AH5SA-O4C1G1LYZHQ# being the latest WIP development for shasper (sharding + casper FFG), plus you can keep an eye on the sharding and casper categories on ethresear.ch or watch these categories to be notified of new posts if you're keen, although I suggest to only do that if you're actively involved in R&D, particularly in implementing or scrutinising/critiquing research ideas. There's also a sharding implementers call, although I didn't join the first one. https://github.com/ethresearch/eth2.0-pm.

Comment: Can we also consider this https://github.com/prysmaticlabs/prysm/blob/master/validator/README.md source? Or is too implementation specific?

Comment: You may, although it is implementation specific and repetitive, particularly for me as I already know the research that they refer to. Personally I prefer Rust as my programming language of choice. FMI see e.g. https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/, https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/2018-edition/, and https://medium.com/paritytech/why-rust-846fd3320d3f.